How do Condition Codes work on Out-of-Order processors
In architectures like RISC-V, the register operands for a conditional branch are included in the instruction itself, for example we can have ble rs1, rs2, label which will jump to label if rs1 ≤ rs2. In x86, however, we use condition codes within the FLAGS register that store the result of previous math operations:
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, -1
mov rcx, 0

add rdi, rsi    ; sets ZF to 1 (also stores 0 in rdi)
jle label1      ; taken b/c one of SF or ZF true
sub rcx, rsi    ; sets SF to 1, ZF to 0 (stores -1 in rcx)
jle label2      ; also taken

Sure, technically I should probably be using cmp over actual math instructions but this should still work as expected.
So on an OoO processor, couldn't the sub instruction be deemed independent and moved up before the first jle? One thing I thought of was storing the FLAGS register values in a buffer where the entry is decided in the decode stage (before renaming) of the math instruction and then when a branch is decoded, using the most recent entry for the condition codes since reordering would not have been performed yet.

The cpu is aware that the add and sub update the flags and that the jle reads them. It does not need you to write the operands explicitly to convey that information. For example div also updates registers not given as operands. The flags register can be handled as an additional dependency in the same way as all the other registers (although in some implementations the flags bits may be tracked separately).

The processor implementation, risc or cisc (mov r0,#1, add r1,r1,r0) have to, functionally, perform the tasks described by the programmer.   A conditional branch can start to prepare/compute the two possible destination addresses before the comparison that determines which one is chosen (cisc or risc), but which one is chosen has to be after the comparison has completed.   Silicon folks have options as to how to do that whether it is superscaler, out of order or linear based on cost, performance or power, and may change their mind from one implementation to another...cisc or risc.

yes, flags and values loaded from ram and alu computed values can all have some sort of buffering for perhaps faster access, remember that takes more routing and flops which is additional size, power and cost.  The designers take the instruction set, a deep pipe and create algorithms/rules for what does or does not have a conflict so they can shuffle them about execution units.

"So on an OoO processor, couldn't the sub instruction be ... moved up before the first jle?" — yes, it could be executed quite early, but if it is the processor implementation that does that must still honor the instruction set with regard to all registers including flags and program execution order.  That's part of the complexity that has to be dealt with by such a processor.

For sub rcx, rsi    ; sets SF to 1, ZF to 0 (stores -1 in rcx) the operation is (0) - (-1) and it will produce RCX=1.

The condition-codes part of FLAGS is renamed like for general-purpose integer registers so dependencies can be tracked without having to serialize execution for WAW / WAR hazards like this.
Register renaming avoids WAW and WAR hazards so instruction-level parallelism is only limited by RAW (Read-after-Write) true dependencies.  So indeed the sub can execute before the add, but both jle instructions still read the correct FLAGS input when they execute to check the prediction made by the branch predictor.
In fact most x86 designs rename CF separately from the rest of the condition codes (SPAZO) because some instructions like dec/inc leave CF unmodified.   Older Intel needed to invent a merging uop when something read both halves that had been written by different instructions, e.g. cmp/inc/setbe (reads CF and ZF), or when the most recent FLAGS-write wasn't the one being read (adc in a dec/jnz loop). Or worse, stall the front-end for a few cycles while that happened in P6-family.  Newer Intel (Broadwell and later) simply has instructions like seta/jbe read CF and SPAZO as separate inputs, avoiding a merging uop or partial-flag stall, taking advantage of the ability to track 3-input uops which was added to support FMA but useful for single-uop adc as well.  Unfortunately this makes cmovbe a 4-input instruction so it still decodes as 2 uops, and for some reason also setbe which does an RMW on the low byte of a register plus reading both parts of FLAGS.  Handling this in a simple way in the pre-decoders hurts legacy-decode throughput for all cmovcc/setcc opcodes on Intel.
Pentium 4 didn't rename CF separately, giving inc/dec a false dependency on the last instruction to write CF. (INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter? - not much anymore, and only maybe on low-power E-cores)

In typical implementations, Physical Register File (PRF) entries have enough room to hold an integer and FLAGS, so add and sub still only have one output as far as the out-of-order exec machinery is concerned.  Instructions like cmp that only write FLAGS still allocate one entry in the integer PRF, as do instructions like lea, not, or a mov-load which write an integer register but not FLAGS.


So on an OoO processor, couldn't the sub instruction be deemed independent and moved up before the first jle?

Not on a correctly-designed processor!  The cardinal rule of out-of-order exec is to preserve the behaviour of single-threaded code, so it runs as-if each instruction finished executing before the next one started, in accordance with what the ISA rules describe for the execution model.  (Some ISAs like the Mill and Itanium have some explicit parallelism; see the VLIW section in Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!.  And I'm ignoring things like TLB invalidation rules which do account for speculative TLB prefetch which might need invalidation for a page used by an instruction that hasn't run yet.)
On a hypothetical microarchitecture that didn't rename FLAGS, it would have to detect that write-after-write hazard between add and sub and run them in the right order, and detect the write-after-read hazard (the sub after the first jle) and potentially stall for it.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Data_hazards
Real x86 CPUs can rename FLAGS as many times per cycle as their max uop throughput, i.e. same as the width of the issue/rename unit. So add instead of lea for example is never a throughput bottleneck.
I assume out-of-order exec CPUs for other ISAs with condition codes (like AArch64) are broadly similar in being able to rename it multiple times per cycle.
PowerPC is interesting in having multiple condition registers so you can software-pipeline some compares and branches (or branchless conditional-move data dependencies).  This would be more important for in-order exec machines.
See also:

Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!
https://www.agner.org/optimize/ especially his microarchitecture PDF, although I forget if he goes into a lot of detail about register renaming and the fact that it avoids false dependencies.  More focus on potential bottlenecks in each pipeline stage.
https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ and other articles, good deep-dives into the microarchitectures and the benefits of the design choices they make.
Can the simple decoders in recent Intel microarchitectures handle all 1-µop instructions?
What is a Partial Flag Stall? - some details about how Intel CPUs rename FLAGS like I discussed in the second paragraph.


"(Some ISAs like the Mill and Itanium have some explicit parallelism (see the VLIW section in Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!." Missing one closing paren.

@ecm: Thanks, fixed.
